# KODI player complex json array I need values to be process by PHP 5.2

Tags: php, json

Hi I having a problem with json responce from Kodi Player I need to extract two values like channelid and label i need to be done in PHP 5.2

```
{"id":"libGetChannels","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"channels":[{"channel":"BBC
 One HD","channelid":3,"label":"BBC One HD","lastplayed":"2018-08-16"}, 
{"channel":"BBC Two HD","channelid":4,"label":"BBC Two 
HD","lastplayed":"2018-08-16"}],"limits":{"end":2,"start":0,"total":2}}}
```

thanks for helping me i'm new in Json

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: I need a php script that will will get channelid and label from that json code

Answer (score 0):

```
    $json = '{"id":"libGetChannels","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"channels":[{"channel":"BBC One HD","channelid":3,"label":"BBC One HD","lastplayed":"2018-08-16"},{"channel":"BBC Two HD","channelid":4,"label":"BBC Two HD","lastplayed":"2018-08-16"}],"limits":{"end":2,"start":0,"total":2}}}';

    $array = json_decode($json);
    $channelsArray = [];

    foreach ($array as $value){
        if(is_object($value)){
           foreach ($value->channels as $channel){
               $channelsArray[] = $channel;
           }
        }
    }

    foreach($channelsArray as $channel){
        echo $channel->channelid;
        echo $channel->label;
    }
```

Comment: can you please provide example for PHP 5.2 because this works on PHP 5.5

Comment: @Kamil Szynkiewicz
    $channelsArray = array();